# Azure keyvault CLI - how to have a space in the value

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I'm using Azure's `az` CLI to interact with KeyVault and I don't know how to include a space in the value of the secret I'm trying to set. As of azure cli version 2.0.46, proper syntax for setting a secret is:

`az keyvault secret set --vault-name NAME --name SECRET_NAME --value VALUE`

If VALUE is "my value" (without quotes), I get an error for too many arguments. If I include the quotes on the command line, they show up in the actual value (in this example, the value will be `\"my value\"`. I can put my value in a file and use the `-f` flag but this can be inconvenient and sometimes impossible depending on the access permissions with the filesystem.

Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: `'my value'`? does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it could be argued that my original question and attempt wasn't really valid but it's nuanced. It turns out this is a shell variable expansion problem, not an issue with quotes in the `az` CLI.

`--value VALUE` where `VALUE` is `"my value"` is *NOT* the same as `--value "VALUE"` where `VALUE` is `my value`. I was thinking that, after the expansion, they would be the exact same command.

Here are some concrete commands -

`az keyvault secret set ... --value $VALUE` when `$VALUE` = `my value` shows the "expected one argument" error.

`az keyvault secret set ... --value $VALUE` when `$VALUE` = `"my value"` stores `\"my value\"` in the vault.

`az keyvault secret set ... --value "$VALUE"` when `$VALUE` = `my value` stores `my value` in the vault (as I wanted)

`az keyvault secret set ... --value '$VALUE'` when `$VALUE` = `my value` stores `my value` in the vault (same as double quotes)